# ElasticSearch returning fragments well over the fragment size

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following to set my highlighter in elasticsearch

```
{ 
  pre_tags: ["<b>"], 
  post_tags: ["</b>"], 
  fields: { 
    title: { number_of_fragments: 0 },                                           
    body:  { number_of_fragments: 1, fragment_size: 200, type: "plain" }
  }
}
```

however I am occasionally getting the body highlight to be upwards of 300 characters in length and I am unsure why - it's rare, but every now and then a search result will come through with a really long search fragment.

My temporary fix is that I will truncate the result manually, but I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: I have the same issue. Had any luck fixing it yet?

Comment: Same here, I'd like to know if anyone has figured it out! Thanks!